# Make File Error *** No rule to make target `3', needed by `run'. Stop

Tags: c, makefile

I am creating a makefile for C, I am passing two arguments via the command line. This is what I am running on the command line.

```
    dipesh@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ make run H=3 C=3
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Make File Error *** No rule to make target `3', needed by `run'.  Stop
```

This is my make file

```
all: forkk.o
     gcc -Wall fork.o -o forkk.out
forkk.o: forkk.c
     gcc -Wall -c forkk.c

run: ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)

clean:
     rm forkk
```

Comment: move the stuff after `:` to the next indented line.

Comment: Note that compilation line your `all` rule uses `fork.o` but that isn't available (and the dependency is on `forkk.o`).  Usually, you'd make `all` depend on `forkk.out`, and have a rule to compile `forkk.out` from `forkk.o` (or use a built-in rule to build direct from `forkk.c`).

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific on Eugene's comment, this line:

```
run: ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
```

is wrong.  You've put the recipe (command to be invoked) on the same line as the target, so make thinks that the recipe command is actually a set of prerequisites.  When you run:

```
make H=3 C=3
```

this line expands to:

```
run: ./forkk.out 3 3
```

and make tries to find a way to build a prerequisite "3" causing the error you see.

You want this:

```
run:
        ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
```

If you really want it to be on one line you have to use a `;` to separate the rule from the recipe line:

```
run: ; ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
```

Answer (score 2):

This rule ...

> ```
> run: ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
> ```

... says that the "run" target has `./forkk.out` and the expansions of variables `$(H)` and `$(C)` as its dependencies.  When you ask `make` to build that target -- which you do -- it first ensures that those dependencies are up to date.  Since `$(H)` and `$(C)` both expand to `3`, `make` looks in its working directory for a file named `3`.  Not finding any such file, and not having any applicable rule to build one, it bails.

You probably meant this, instead:

```
run:
     ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
```

.  There, the `run` target has *no* dependencies, so its recipe, starting (and ending) on the next line, is executed every time that target is built.

Do note, however, that the `run` target does have a *bona fide* dependency on `forkk.out`, which that revised rule does not express.  And that's probably just as well, because it is not a target either, so `make` does not know how to build it.  A more robust Makefile would introduce both the dependency and the target, something like this:

```
all: forkk.out

forkk.out: forkk.o
     gcc -Wall forkk.o -o forkk.out

forkk.o: forkk.c
     gcc -Wall -c forkk.c

run:
     ./forkk.out $(H) $(C)
```

Note also that your `clean` rule cleans a file that none of the other rules create, and fails to clean some that the other rules do create.  It probably ought to be

```
clean:
     rm -f forkk.out forkk.o
```